# Different torques on a single rigid body

Tags: torque, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

Assume I have a rigid body, on which two different torques are applied on two different surface points.

I can calculate body inertia at each of those points. Describe the torques to the frame attached to each of the points. And find the resulting angular velocities at each of the contact point frames.

Now apparently I can define the resulting angular velocities in the world frame, but I can not add them up, can I?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer. My contact with physics is only tangential, so I am not sure if the answer is correct. Suppose you want to model the dynamics of the rigid body. Consider a world coordinate system in which the center of mass has the coordinates $G = (x_g,y_g,z_g)$. Suppose that the first force $F_1 = (f_{1x}, f_{1y}, f_{1z})_w$ is acting on the point $P_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1)_w$. Similar for the second force, $F_2 = (f_{2x}, f_{2y}, f_{2z})_w$ acting on the second point $P_2 = (x_2,y_2,z_2)_w$. Suppose the body has the mass $M$ and the matrix of inertia in a coordinate system centered in the center of mass and parallel with the world axis, $I_B$. For the movement of the center of mass one can use $$\frac{dP}{dt} = F_1 + F_2$$ where $P = M\cdot (\dot{x}_g, \dot{y}_g, \dot{z}_g)$. For the rotation of the body one has $$ \tau = \frac{dL}{dt} = (P_1 - G) \times F_1 + (P_2 - G)\times F_2$$ The difficult part is to write the angular momentum of the body. If you know an axis of rotation generated by the first force, $F_1$ which is precessed by the other force, $F_2$ then: the angular momentum due to first axis is $L_1 = I_B\cdot \omega_1$. The other force rotates this axis $\omega_1$ around $\omega_2$ then $$ \tau = \frac{dL}{dt} = \omega_2 \times L_1$$ I think ...

Comment: Thank you C Marius for the answer, but as I had also mentioned in my question, in my assumption, there are only two pure torques applying on the object..

Comment: Ok! I hope the answer was useful thou ...